# on open window browser

Tags: javascript

is it possible to default a window size to 1280 width on websites not full screen?

If we can default it to that size would it be a problem for people who only has their resolution set on 1024?

Comment: As much as this is possible per the answers provided, I would recommend avoiding this. Forcing browser windows to open to a set size is bad interface design and does not make for a good user experience. Having a minimum requirement is fine, but forcing your users to have specific browser sizes kind of defeats the purpose of a web browser and the freedom the web allows it's users in how they experience it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to default a window
>   size to 1280 width on websites not
>   full screen?

- Yes, you can set a browser window [size with javascript](http://www.cybertext.com.au/tips_HTML_window_size.htm).

> If we can default it to that size
>   would it be a problem for people who
>   only has their resolution set on 1024?

- The best practice is to check the screen resolution before you do this, and you can [check that with javascript as well](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jscreen.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com",
"mywindow","resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=1280,height=250");
```

Check [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

scrollbars=1 will take care of the 1024 screen size.